# Create a CANoe test environment for xml module using python

Tags: python, scripting

I want to create a CANoe test environment and want to include a xml test module to it using python or any other automation script. is it possible ?
   The number xml modules i want to include may vary dynamically. Any help would be appreciated. And thanks in advance.

Comment: This site is for addressing specific software problems where you have at least tried to solve them yourself - not software recommendations you should try SoftwareRecs http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions but you will still need to be a lot more specific.

Comment: okay Mr. Steve Barnes.   I found out my solution thanks for your advice